# Copy style in openpyxl with reference to new cell

Tags: python, excel, copy, cell, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet in which a value of a cell is referred to another one.
For example in C9 -> `=D10`.
I add 2 rows above the row 9(with openpyxl), and I copy the row belows(the previous 9 and 10) in this way(here copying only a cell):

```
sheetname.cell(row=9, column=3).value = sheetname.cell(row=11, column=3).value
sheetname.cell(row=9, column=3)._style = copy(sheetname.cell(row=11, column=3)._style)
```

(now the old row 9 is row 11, and the row 9 is the new one added).

The style is copied, but the reference isn't anymore `D10`, but it is the reference of the old cell(now `D12`).
How can I make dynamic the reference and have in C9 -> `=D10`again?
Thanks[image]

Comment: My advice is not to do this. Nowhere in the library do we suggest you copy styles like this between cells.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `=D10` in `C9`try to type it as `=$D$10`